# Why are these numbers not summing in a for loop using javascript?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm iterating over a range, extracting 2 texts (to be converted into numbers) and summing them to put the total back into the stirng later.
However, although I see the numbers logged ok, the sums give me `NaN` as the results.
Here's the code piece:

```
  var totalPriceToPay = 0;
  var totalCODAmount = 0;
  if (ss.getActiveSheet().getName() == sheet.getName() && row > 1) {
    for (var a = 0; a < dataRng.length; a++) {
      if (dataRng[a][1] == true && dataRng[a][0] == 'SHIPPED' && dataRng[a][40] != 'Yes') {

        //Isolate the Price to Pay Amounts to be summed and put the total back into the string.
        const str = dataRng[a][35].toString();
        const priceToPay = str.split(",").slice(8, 9)[0] //Extracts 8th element
        totalPriceToPay += Number(priceToPay) //Converts it into a nº and sums to the total

        const codAmount = str.split(',').slice(9, 10)[0] //Extracts the 9th element
        totalCODAmount += Number(codAmount) //Converts it into a nº and sums to the total

        Logger.log('Type Price To Pay: ' + str.split(",").slice(8, 9)[0]);
        Logger.log('Type codAmount: ' + str.split(",").slice(9, 10)[0]);
        Logger.log('Total Price to Pay: ' + totalPriceToPay);
        Logger.log('Total COD: ' + totalCODAmount);
```

Here are the logs:
[image]

Thanks.

Comment: So the problem is Number(), try with parseInt()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The numbers have a `$` before it. You need to remove it. Use [`String.slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice):

```
const priceToPay = Number(str.split(",")[8].slice(1));
```

Answer (score 1):

The `Number()` constructor will give `NaN` when the value cannot be converted to a number. When you add `NaN` to a number, you get `NaN`. To avoid the issue, use this pattern:

```
        totalPriceToPay += Number(priceToPay) || 0;
        totalCODAmount += Number(codAmount) || 0;
```